# How to make an linux kernel project in eclipse ctd?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to do some Linux kernel programming. I have chosen Eclipse CDT as my IDE but i can't seem to get a project started. By started i mean that i can't get trough the project wizard.
I have followed different tutorials like this one: 
[Link to tutorial](http://issaris.blogspot.nl/2007/12/download-linux-kernel-sourcecode-from.html)
On the select configuration screen when i press finish the program doesn't continue (there is a loading bar, but it dissapiears quickly).
Can anyone give me some pointers to solve this problem? I run Ubuntu 12.04 on a parallels virtual machine on a Macbook.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as working directory is use /usr/local/src/linux(here is the downloaded kernel source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the directory containing your kernel source is owned by 'root'. I faced that problem and resolved it by doing a `sudo chown -hR my_user_name my_kernel_dir`. Sadly Eclipse (3.8.1) does not show any visible warning.